# nativescript telerik sidedrawer is appears to be totally transparent, how do resolve this?

Tags: android, telerik, nativescript

[image: nativescript sidedrawer]

Here is my whole sidedrawer is totally transparent how do i get the drawer as shown in the telerik-ui in nativescript.

```
  <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer">
      <drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
        <StackLayout>
      <ListView items="{{myitems}}" itemTap="ontap">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
          <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label text="{{name}}" class="list"/>
            <Label class="bar-font"  text="&#xf105;" id="point" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
      </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
      </drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
      <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent class="drawer">
        <GridLayout class="drawer-content">
          <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Survey" tap="surveytap"/>
            <Label text="Forms" tap="formstap"/>
            <Label text="Profile" tap="profiletap"/>
            <Label text="Logout" tap="logouttap"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
      </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    </drawer:RadSideDrawer>
</StackLayout>
```

my css:

```
.drawer-content {
  background-color: #053140;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20;
}

.drawer-content Label {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20;
  margin: 10 0 15 25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some styling to the drawer. Specifically `backgroundColor`. I forget from memory the actual markup of the drawer. If you post the XML I can point it out, otherwise just add the prop to the XML markup or add a CSS class to the component.

Comment: i have posted my xml file .I have tried to use some css class but it doesn't work

Comment: where you have `class="drawer"` on the `.drawerContent` let's try hardcoding the `backgroundColor` prop. Something like this: `backgroundColor="#3489db"` on the opening `.drawerContent` tag should do it. Also are you running `livesync` making the changes, or doing a new build? If you're running livesync, sometimes there are issues with different environments that I've noticed and this could be an issue for you. So do a new build and run it and you should see the changes reflected.

Comment: i have done as you said css worked fro styling font but i was unable to set the backgroud color it comes as it is no change could plz help me to sort out this ....